# setDataSource failed 0x8000000

Tags: android

I am receiving an error (setDataSource failed 0x8000000) when using MediaMetadataRetriever to retrieve the artist and title of an mp3 file, but I cannot understand why. When running on my emulator, it works perfectly, but crashes when running on my Samsung S4. I know the directory is correct (/storage/extSdCard/Music/) because I can load file names without any problem whatsoever. Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

```
        if (songs.size() != 0){
            for (int x = 0; x < songs.size(); x++){
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(x));

                String tagTitle =
                     mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                String tagArtist =
                     mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);


                taggedSongs.add(tagArtist + " - " + tagTitle);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item,taggedSongs);
```

EDIT:

Logcat:

```
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jimmy.jimp3/com.jimmy.jimp3.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:66)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.jimmy.jimp3.MainActivity.taggedPlaylist(MainActivity.java:78)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.jimmy.jimp3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
09-15 10:55:02.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my post to include it

Comment: Did you set the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`-permission?

Comment: The error you get means that the file is corrupt, or your FD doesn't support seek.

Comment: I haven't written that permission, no. Is it necessary? As I say it works on my emulator, so I don't think that's the problem. If I had a file that doesn't have tags, could it cause this issue? I only have 2 files on my emulator and both of those are tagged, however on my phone I have several files without tags.

Comment: Problem solved, it was caused by files that don't have any tags. I can't answer my own question yet because I don't have enough rep so I'll update later

Comment: What do you mean when `it was caused by files that don't have any tags.`

Comment: Hey Can you now answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by my forgetting to set INTERNET permission while my app requires access to the internet. Rookie error.

Answer (score -2):

Puting the setDataSource() method in try-catch block solved the issue.

```
  try {
            metaRetriver.setDataSource(AudioPath);
           //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
```